# error by running a bash command in Perl script

Tags: perl, bash, awk

I wrote a Perl script in order to automate a process for sending a lot of jobs in an lsf based cluster.
The problem is that for a reason that I don't get it cuts the line with the job in two lines, and the job cannot run.
here is my script:

```
my $controler = $ARGV[0];


open my $cont, $controler or die "Could not open $controler: $!";
my $str = qx(wc -l $controler | awk '{print $1}');
#my $str2 = system($str);
#my @count = split /\n/,$str;
#print $str;
for (my $f = 1; $f <= $str; $f++) {
#print $count[0];
`mkdir ~/Multiple_alignments/ELEMENTS-AUTO-$f`;
#`mkdir ../SCORES-AUTO-$f`;
}

while ( $cont = <>){
    chomp;
    my @lines = split /\t/, $cont;
    my $count2 = $lines[0];
    my $cover = $lines[1];
    my $length = $lines[2];
    my $rho = $lines[3];

     my @files = <*maf>;
    foreach my $file (@files) {
    #print $file . "\n";
    my $base = basename($file, ".maf");
    #print "$base\n";
    #print "$cover\n";
    #print "$length\n";
    #print "$rho\n";

 print "`bsub -q q_cf_htc_work -R \"select[type==X86_64 && mem>6000]\" rusage[mem=6000] -M6000 -o /home/vasilis.lenis/Multiple_alignments/out-files/phastCons_$base.o -e    /home/vasilis.lenis/Multiple_alignments/out-files/phastCons_$base.e -J phastCons$base phastCons --target-coverage $cover --expected-length $length --rho $rho --most-conserved ../ELEMENTS-AUTO-$count2/most_conserved_$base.bed --msa-format MAF $file mytrees_no3.noncons.mod --no-post-probs`\n";

            }

 }
```

I just cannot understand why its happening.
(Also, the awk command that I have at the third line doesn't work)

Thank you in advance,
Vasilis.

Comment: Sounds like you have a newline in some variable. Unfortunately I can't tell you which one, because you gave *very* little information. You don't need to use either `wc` or `awk` in Perl. You are overwriting your file handle with `$cont = <>`, but then you're reading the file anyway because you are using the diamond operator `<>`.

Comment: Im using the awk just to make as much directories as the lines of controller file. I have to make the directories before it starts to read the lines of the controller. The controller file has 4 columns (tabs separated) and at the last number (the $rho variable) has new line, but for that reason i'm using the chomp.

Comment: @Vasilis, read http://stackoverflow.com/help/asking and come up with a minimal example that reproduces your problem.

Comment: A suggestion: It is better to use built-in 'mkdir'(http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/mkdir.html) or File::Path module (http://perldoc.perl.org/File/Path.html) for directory creation instead of calling *nix command 'mkdir'.

Comment: Why use `my $str = qx(wc -l $controler | awk '{print $1}');` in the first place? Using Perl, you also can archive this, and your script will be more portable.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you very much for your guidance.
I believe that I solved the problem with the new line.
I was using wrong the chomp function.
       chomp($cont);